# Editing GBM Source code, C++ part of code

Tags: c++, r, gbm

I am new to R. I have been playing around GBM source code for learning.

I am trying to change different existing conditions and formulas in source code.

I am able to edit R codes using fix() and trace(), but c++ codes of GBM i am not able to edit and put those edited codes in place of existing and run them to see the impact of change in the existing conditions/formulas.

Is it possible to change  c++ codes of GBM and run GBM with the edited code ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

C++ codes will work only after compilation. Most packages have precompiled C/C++ codes for faster execution. Please check if there is any compilation step or other hints.

Without compiling C++ code you are observing old code behavior only and hence no changes in output, even after your changes.

Comment: I have not found any compilation step or other hints. I sit possible i create another package with these edited codes and run them ? If yes, could you please let me know where i can find those process ?

Comment: Thanks. Now I have idea how to proceed with create package